# Raspberry PI - pinging multiple IPs

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi2

Would either like the code analysed and fixed or point me in the right direction please.  So many errors, some overcome, others not.

Program runs on a Raspberry PI2 and should try and ping specific IP addresses and return a result.

Very new to programming, you can probably tell! Not sure if I need a ping library or can do it without

```
import sys
import time
from pushbullet import Pushbullet
import serial

class Users(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, ip=None):
        self.name = name
        self.ip = ip
        self.status = 'out'
pb = Pushbullet("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") #Pushbullet ID removed

userList = []
userList.append(Users("Ali", "192.18.1.14"))
userList.append(Users("Sophie", "192.18.1.9"))
userList.append(Users("TV", "192.18.1.7"))

try:
    while True: 
        print "Checking... " + time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
        for user in userList:
            result = os.system ("ping -n 1 " = user.ip)
            oldStatus = user.status
            if (result == 0):
                    #What we'll do if a device is detected
                if (oldStatus == 'out'):
                    push = pb.push_note("Home Pi", user.name + " is home")
                    user.status = 'in'
                print user.name + " is home"
            else:
                 #What we'll do if a device is NOT not detected
                if (oldStatus == 'in'):
                    push = pb.push_note("Home Pi", user.name + " has just left")
                    user.status = 'out'
                print user.name + " is out"

        print "Next check will be in 30 seconds"
        time.sleep(30)

        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to work, i don't have pushbullet. Compare my new code with your previous to see the difference and the errors

```
import sys
import time
#from pushbullet import Pushbullet
#import serial
#you need import os
import os

class Users(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, ip=None):
        self.name = name
        self.ip = ip
        self.status = 'out'
#pb = Pushbullet("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") #Pushbullet ID removed

userList = []
userList.append(Users("Notebook", "192.168.1.2"))
userList.append(Users("TV", "192.168.1.4"))

try:
    while True: 
        print "Checking... " + time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
        for user in userList:
            #result = os.system ("ping -n 1 " = user.ip)
        # to concatenate string you need + sign
            #result = os.system("ping -n 1 " + user.ip)
            # -n is a wrong option for ubuntu
            result = os.system("ping -c 1 " + user.ip)
            oldStatus = user.status
            if (result == 0):
                    #What we'll do if a device is detected
                if (oldStatus == 'out'):
                    #push = pb.push_note("Home Pi", user.name + " is home")
                    user.status = 'in'
                print user.name + " is home"
            else:
                 #What we'll do if a device is NOT not detected
                if (oldStatus == 'in'):
                    #push = pb.push_note("Home Pi", user.name + " has just left")
                    user.status = 'out'
                print user.name + " is out"

        print "Next check will be in 30 seconds"
        time.sleep(30)

#wrong identation
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
  sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your help and assistance.  Comparing the two really helped to understand the errors, so learnt a lot too.  Is there an easy way to mute the ping output?  The return is the packet details and  and I'd prefer not to have these shown, only the user.name? Thanks

Comment: try this: result = os.system("ping -c 1 " + user.ip + " >/dev/null")